# How to find general inverse of a matrix

Tags: matrices

> Find the general inverse (G) of the matrix 
>   $$A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 \\4 & 5 & 6\end{bmatrix}$$
>   Also check that $AGA=A$

I am new in G- inverse calculation. I understand that G will be a $3 \times 2$ matrix. But unable to find it. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: General inverse? You probably mean generalized?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A$ be a full rank $m\times n$ matrix. By full rank we mean $\DeclareMathOperator{rank}{rank}\rank(A)=\min\{m,n\}$.

- If $m<n$, then $A$ has a *right inverse* given by
  $$
  A^{-1}_{\text{right}}=A^\top(AA^\top)^{-1}
  $$
- If $m>n$, then $A$ has a *left inverse* given by
  $$
  A^{-1}_{\text{left}}=(A^\top A)^{-1} A^\top
  $$

Our matrix $A$ is $2\times 3$ with rank two, so $A$ has a right inverse given by
$$
A_{\text{right}}^{-1}=
\begin{bmatrix}
-17/18 & 4/9 \\
-1/9 & 1/9 \\
13/18 & -2/9
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Putting $G=A_{\text{right}}^{-1}$ then gives
$$
AGA=AA_{\text{right}}^{-1}A=AI=A
$$

Comment: if you would have given the way of finding all the generalized inverse of it would be fine..@Brian